# Getting only one the first object from a grouped and filtered list of object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a list of `CalendarData` and I am getting the object with the max EventValue after grouped the objects by hour the list.

The issue is that when I have two `CalandarData` in the same hour range with the same Max EventValue I am getting both and I only one the first.

I don't know where I can apply the .First() extension method on this syntax. Any good idea thanks

```
List<CalendarData> listData =
    filteredlistCalendarData.GroupBy(element => element.StartTime.Hour)
                            .SelectMany(
                                 group => group.Where(element => element.EventValue == group.Max(obj => obj.EventValue))
                                               .Take(1))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Hi Marcin I tested again you answer and it work properly I was missing the parenthesis and when I added it I slightly modified braking the code. If want you can add the solution so another people can access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OrderByDescending` and `FirstOrDefault`:

```
                             group => group.OrderByDescending(e => e.EventValue)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()
```

To make it work replace `SelectMany` call with `Select`:

```
filteredlistCalendarData.GroupBy(element => element.StartTime.Hour)
                        .Select(
                             group => group.OrderByDescending(e => e.EventValue)
                                           .FirstOrDefault())
                        .ToList();
```